# OrderBy calculate propritie Entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, entitymanager

entity:

```
 class Pharmacie{    
      public $distance;

     public function getDistance() {
          // calculate distance here 
          return $distance; 
    }

}
```

and in controller:

```
 public function listePharmsGeoAction()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();


    $pharmas = $em->getRepository('CentraleFrontBundle:Pharmacie')
                   ->createQueryBuilder('o')
                   ->orderBy('o.distance','ASC')
                   ->getQuery()
                   ->getResult();



     return $this->render('CentraleFrontBundle:SiteFront:listePharms.html.twig', array(
        'pharmas' => $pharmas));
}
```

error: [Semantical Error] line 0, col 65 near 'distance ASC': Error: Class Centrale\FrontBundle\Entity\Pharmacie has no field or association named distance

Comment: You don't have distance property in your Pharmacie entity... What's the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- it's a bad practice to create query directly in your controller, you should create function in your repository
- distance property should be protected or private not public
- where is your mapping ???

Comment: think u for your response bat distance has not table column to mapping is calculate with address and ip filed

Comment: Ok, so it's normal, you can't order by a non existent column.

Comment: how i can order by calculate propriety ?